# How to use the smooth tool in weight paint mode?

Tags: weight-painting

I'm curious as to what I need to do to use the smooth tool in weight paint mode in Blender. The notice says:

> Vertex select needs to be enabled in weight paint mode.

Great!  How does one enable vertex select in weight paint mode?

[image: Smooth tool disabled]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The vertex select can be enabled in the 3D View header -

[image]

With vertex select masking enabled you can use Shift-Click to select/de-select each vertex from the mask. You can also go into edit mode, select the desired vertices then go into weight paint mode.